# How to scale from left to right only

Tags: html, css, scale

This is my css code

```
 body
 {
  transform: scaleX(0.67);
 }
```

In this my entire website shrink both from right and left.but i need only scale from left how can i do this

Comment: use transform-origin,css property.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe the transform-origin can be helpful here:

```
body {
    transform:scale(0.67);
    transform-origin:left center;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You add `transform-origin` which define from which position the transform should occur.

Its default value is `center center` (`50% 50%`) and you need `left center` (`0 50%`)

```
body
{
  transform: scaleX(0.67);
  transform-origin: left center;
}
```